# Proof of limit question

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to find how large $n$ needs to be for:

$$(a^{n}+b^{n})^{1/n}$$

to be less than some number $x$.

What method could I use to do this? In examples for similar sorts of questions, I have seen the binomial theorem used, is this applicable?

Comment: You have to define what is a and b first.

Comment: Done. I don't have a specific value of a,b in mind, I just want to know the method

Comment: E.g., if $a=b$, then the limit is $a$.

Comment: I know what the limit is, but I need to know how to find how large n has to be for it to be within some x of the limit

Comment: You mean you need to find $n$ so that $|(a^n+b^n)^{1/n} - \max\{a,b\}| < x$, or do you want it to simply be the case that $|(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}| < x$?

Comment: Would it help to solve $(a^n+b^n)^{\frac 1 n} = x$ for n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose $n$ large enough for $a^n + b^n < x^n$, since that implies $(a^n + b^n)^{1/n} < x$.

EDIT: As for finding the minimum such $n$, you could simply find an $n$ that is large enough and then do a binary search with an $n$ that is smaller. I'm not sure that you can solve $a^n + b^n = x^n$ for $n$ analytically.

Comment: the question is how to choose the minimum n that satisfy that condition...

Comment: I have that written down, but then how do I go about solving that for n?

Comment: good question...

Comment: Say I had a=1 b=2 and x=10^(-3), would that be easy to solve?

Comment: i thought you know x and want to compute n, didn't you?

Comment: for what you commented, x=5 is a solution, that's too easy...

Comment: Yes sorry I want n, I meant x=10^(-3). I don't think trial and improvement is a good enough method.

Comment: it would be easy to solve numerically... but I'm not sure if it is possible analytically...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, for the sake of simplicity, that $\;a\ge b>0\;$, and use the squeeze theorem :

$$a=(a^n)^{1/n}\le\left(a^n+b^n\right)^{1/n}=a\left(1+\left(\frac ba\right)^n\right)^{1/n}\le a\,\sqrt[n]2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}a$$